# How to control the padding between rows using arrangeGrob?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

While using `gridextra` and `ggplot2` how can I control the padding between rows? I see some large margin between the two rows of my final plot. Even while playing with the padding parameter to have the minimum ...

```
p1 <- ...
p2 <- ...
p3 <- ...
final <- gridExtra::arrangeGrob(p1, p2, p3, layout_matrix = rbind(c(1,2), c(3,3)), heights=c(3,7), 
                                padding = unit(0.1, "line"))
ggplot2::ggsave(filename=output.file,plot=final,width=18,height=9)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `padding` parameter is for annotations (title, etc.). The spacing between plots should be adjusted by the plot margins,

```
pl <- replicate(3, ggplot(), FALSE)

pl <- lapply(pl, function(p) p + theme(plot.margin = margin(t=50, l=50)))

gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = pl, layout_matrix = rbind(c(1,2), c(3,3)), heights=c(3,7))
```

[image]